# Ubuntu 20.04 USB boot keeps loading

Tags: boot, 20.04, freeze

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 using Live USB. But, right after performing the disk checks, boot is stuck this stage.

[image]

Comment: If you hit the [Esc] key, do you see any messages?

Comment: Yeah, I do. Service logs mostly.

Comment: Edit your question and show us a picture of the screen after hitting ESC.

Comment: How old is your HP?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a new live usb? If yes, the image file may be corrupted, so try to download it again and make another live usb.

Comment: I tried that a couple of times but same thing happens again and again. Same thing happens for Ubuntu 21 also.

Comment: Try to install it using a USB 2.0 port

Answer (score 0):

does you computer connected to KVM or other USB components (other than your USB of course)?
it might be the issue.

in addition, how did you created the live USB? try with Rufus if not used already